# Angular 2: Redirecting route changes component but doesn't replace URL

Tags: angular, redirect, routes

I have an Angular 2.0.0 SPA with the following type of app.routes.ts (simplified):

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Page1Component } from  './page1/page1.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: "page1", component: Page1Component},
  { path: "page2", redirectTo: "page1"}
];
```

page1.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Page1Component } from './page1.component.ts';

export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Page1Component, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Page1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class Page1Module {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

With this, going to http://localhost:3000/#/page2 loads page1, but the path doesn't change to page1.  If I reload the page, then the URL changes to http://localhost:3000/#/page2.

Any ideas of what is wrong/how to fix this?

Comment: I am not expert but, I think  this may help https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect

Comment: Redirecting default route works just fine.  What seems to be the problem in my situation is that both routes (the original and the redirect route) are on the same level of navigation.

Comment: @AnnaT did you ever find a solution to this?